# Substituir texto com JS em determinada URL

Tags: javascript

Olá como posso fazer para substituir alguma parte do meu link por JS exemplo

https://meusite.com.br/arquivos/ids/785837-90-90/arquivo

Preciso trocar os 2 "90" por "160"

Comment: Só substituir? Talvez a function `replace` ajude: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Apenas com a informação que indica não funciona para outros números, ou será sempre a apenas `90` ?. Melhor seria dar mais exemplos de substituições que queira fazer de forma a se identificar um padrão

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar o `replace`

```js
let url = 'https://meusite.com.br/arquivos/ids/785837-90-90/arquivo'

let newUrl = url.replace(/90/g, '160')

console.log(newUrl)
```